# drawing/plotting library for 3D rendering from x,y,z points

Tags: library, java, c++, plotting

I have been doing some extensive research for a Java/C++ library to produce realistic drawings/plottings from X,Y,Z coordinates in a text file.

I'd prefer it this drawings/plottings can be seeing directly on the screen and move the point of view directly.

I want to be able to see them in 3D and change the point of view.

I would prefer open-source code so I can modify the program/library.

I can´t find anything more than Arbaro, which is pretty basic and doesn´t allow (even after looking at the source code) XYZ coordinates. http://arbaro.sourceforge.net/

Does anybody know any library that might suit this characteristics? 
I'd prefer C++ or Java, but I am open to everything.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially, you might wish to include a full list of requirements (and things not required/wanted), which helps narrowing down things to better matching recommendations.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don't think we need more information, as the broadness of the question is due to I can accept any language and price. The requirement is pretty specific. From coordinates to drawings. Even buying a complete program if it is neccesary as Autocad if it serves for this purpose, but I'd prefer open-source and Java/C++ if possible.

Comment: I can understand *you* don't need more information. But *we* might. We like questions being as precise as possible (as described behind the link in my previous comment). Too broad questions a) tend to be closed (as "too broad"), and b) are often not receiving good or any answers. So I was just giving you a hint how to improve your chances – all else is up to you. As the area is not exactly my expertise, I'll leave it as-is now. Good luck anyhow!

Comment: Take a look at DataMelt Java program (and some examples) in https://jwork.org/dmelt/code/index.php?art=Plots/3D